# javax.faces.FacesException: No file was uploaded

Tags: java, glassfish

I am getting above error when I want to deploy war file to glassfish server from Console.
There is no issue when I am deploying in local machine.But when deploying in Server machine I am getting error.Application , JDK version , Glassfish Server everything is same.but why this error at server machine.

I am using glassfish 4 and JDK7

Please help.

Comment: Is the server JDK version same? JDK7?

Comment: Thanks for response !! yes..I have added jdk7 to asenv.bat of glassfish server.And also building application with jdk7.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue.You need to delete the temp file from your system.
I didnot get this issue When I deleted temp file.